# Simple syntax for creating object with dynamic key

Tags: c#

I've got the following:

```
   List<string> names = new List<string>{"Foo"};
   List<object> data = new List<object>();
   data.Add(new Dictionary<string, object> {{names[0], "Grand Totals"}});
```

This works well, but I'm curious if there's a more simple syntax which would achieve the same result.

I tried:

```
data.Add(new {names[0], "Grand Totals"});
```

but I receive the error:

> Anonymous type projection initializer should be simple name or member access expression.

Comment: I think you may want to refactor this. What problem are you attempting to solve here?

Comment: I'm converting some legacy code which built a representation of a grid server-side to an object which is immediately converted to JSON and interpreted client-side. All of the column names are dynamic so I can't build a class to represent the data. No work is done on "data" after this -- it is simply sent across the wire as JSON.

Comment: Are you going to be adding to data[0] (the dictionary you place there)? Why use object instead of just making a list of dictionary<string,object>?

Comment: That might work, but Dictionary isn't serializable by default in C#... so maybe other fussing needed. I'll play with it a bit.

Comment: Do you think you could give a slightly expanded example? It is hard to work with the narrow version shown. If you don't want to edit too much into here, you can come join us at the [c# chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7/c)

Comment: Seems like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its unclear why `object` is being used for a string, but this achieves the same result sans boxing

```
List<string> names = new List<string>{"Foo"};

List<string> headers = new List<string>() { "Grand Totals" };

var data = names.Zip(headers, (nm, hd) => new { Name = nm, Header = hd })
                .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Name, kvp => kvp.Header );
```

Data looks like this:

[image]